# Format leading zeros on string -- UNIX script

Tags: linux, unix, format

So what I'm trying do do is make a script to read my input file and do stuff accordingly.

My input file gets sent to me in this format:

```
ID     QTY
xxxxxxxxx,xxx
xxxxxxxxx,xx
xxxxxxxxx,xxx
xxxxxxxxx,xx
xxxxxxxxx,xx
```

Sometimes the ID is only 8 digits because of the number being smaller. I need it to be formatted with leading zeros if that occurs. Also, my input file has thousands of lines.

I have this so far

```
echo "${processNew}"

## Read the file line-by-line and output the id.
IFS=','
while read line
do 
    echo "%09d\n" $line

done < ${processNew}
```

Comment: you want to format `xxxxxxxxx,xxx` or `xxxxxxxxx` , the first part only?

Comment: Format a line to be just like this xxxxxxxxx,xxx - where the last 3 x's is the quantity and can freely be more or less.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: You are almost there, just need a little tweak in your code, but without loop :)

write like this if wanna print both the columns

```
awk -F, '{printf "%09d,%d\n" ,$1,$2}' "${processNew}"
```

write like this if wanna print Only ID column

```
awk -F, '{printf "%09d\n" ,$1}' "${processNew}"
```

Comment: Using `awk` is correct, but running `awk` once per line of input is a nonsense.  You should lose the shell loop, and simply provide the input file as a double-quoted argument to `awk` — leading to: `awk -F, '{printf("%.9d,%d\n", $1, $2)}' "${processNew}"` where the parentheses are optional and the use of `%.9d` is equivalent to `%09d` (though there are inscrutable arguments for preferring `%.9d`, they're subtle and not critical).  The unindented presentation of your code is less than desirable too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - you are right, Thanks for letting me know. Edited the answer

Comment: @sayadav - where would I put that code in mine? You mentioned losing the loop?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - could you help me out implementing your code to mine?

Comment: @Adam Horn - you should consider using above code only. Leave the shell you are using . Just assign your file name to variable processNew. It will work.

Comment: @AdamHorn: You replace everything after `echo "${processNew}"` in the script in the question with the single line of `awk` that's in syadav's answer.